# Find transpose of an endomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, transpose

Hello everyone I have the following statement :

> So we have $E$ a vector space with $e_1 , ... , e_n$ as a basis , $\sigma$ a permutation of $ 1,2,...,n$. We are given an endomorphism on $E$ s.t $e_i \rightarrow e_{\sigma(i)}$.

**Statement:**

> It's transpose is the endomorphism on $E^*$ (dual space) s.t :
> $$e_i^* \rightarrow  e_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}$$

I have no clue for how can I prove that it's true (I don't see why it's true)  any hint would be appreciated.

**Attempts**:

I think that how the associated transpose is defined in $E^*$ may help  , I've chosen $e^*_1,..,e^*_n$ as a basis for $E^*$ but it's going nowhere

Comment: I can hardly follow: Why do you delete your post, to repost it now almost verbatim?
$\ddot\frown$
Btw, understanding the transpose, and working in the dual basis quickly leads somewhere. $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_\sigma$ be the permutation endomorphism.

By definition of the transpose, we should have for all $f \in E^*$, $x \in E$

$$\langle ^tu_\sigma(f),x\rangle = \langle f,u_\sigma(x) \rangle.$$

In particular, we should have for all $i,j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$

$$\langle ^tu_\sigma(e_j^*),e_i\rangle = \langle e_j^*,u_\sigma(e_i) \rangle.$$

Let's see what we get if $^tu_\sigma=u_{\sigma^{-1}}$:

$$\langle ^tu_\sigma(e_j^*),e_i\rangle =\langle e_{\sigma^{-1}(j)}^*,e_i \rangle=\langle e_j^*,e_{\sigma(i)} \rangle= \langle e_j^*,u_\sigma(e_i) \rangle.$$

As the transpose is unique, we get the desired conclusion.